# RHEL 7.8 (STIG'd (Locked-Down Image)) targetd faux-iSCSI front-end for Initiators -- Can't log in with CHAP from RHEL 7.8 Initiator

Tags: iscsi, rhel7

Here's my scenario:

- Target: RHEL 7.8 (security lockdowns) using targetd/targetcli to configure /dev/sdb (100GB) presented as a block device and created as LUN0
- Target(new):  RHEL 7.8 (NO SECURITY LOCKDOWNS)
- Initiator:  RHEL 7.8 (security lockdowns) using iscsi-initiator-utils
- Initiator:  Windows Server 2016 using built-in iSCSI utils

TESTS:

1. [RHEL -> RHEL, NO CHAP] works
2. [RHEL(new) -> RHEL (new), NO CHAP] works
3. [Windows -> RHEL, NO CHAP] works
4. [RHEL -> RHEL, CHAP (unidirectional-auth)] Cannot get it to work
5. [RHEL(new) -> RHEL (new), CHAP] WORKS!
6. [Windows -> RHEL, CHAP (unidirectional-auth)] WORKS!

When I originally tried Windows, I got 'Authentication Failed -- password does not conform to the minimum of 12 bytes' so I upped the password to 16 characters and then I got 'Authorization Failed'.  So I took the IQN from the Windows Initiator and applied an ACL and userid/password on the ACL and Windows connected to the RHEL iSCSI front-end fine.

Using this working example, I took the IQN from the RHEL initiator, created an ACL, set the userid/password, and I keep getting authorization failure -- even though the ACL sets correctly:

```
iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2003-01.org.linux-iscsi.localhost.x8664:sn.5d35e2ca9bf3, portal: 192.168.1.16,3260].
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (24 - iSCSI login failed due to authorization failure)
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
```

I've change the password multiple times thinking I was using a bad special character or too short of length and I get the same issue.  I've removed MD5 and SHA1 (leaving SHA256) from the CHAP hash algorithms to get around any limitations due to my locked down image.  I've tried including discovery auth and then trying to discover the target iqn first but that didn't work either.  I bypassed discovery and explicitly set the target via portal address and iqn and get those authorization failures.  I've deleted and recreated the ACL and verified the initiator IQN multiple times...

EDIT:  I created two new RHEL 7.8 boxes (target and initiator) and am able to successfully connect just fine.  Can anyone think of a security setting in the target/initiator side that might be causing this?

Here is the output from my RHEL7.8 targetcli 'ls':

[image]

Any assistance on why I can't get CHAP to work from the RHEL iSCSI Initiator would be greatly appreciated.  TIA!